# Hibernate @Query not producing the required Output

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, hibernate

I am writing a query to return all Orders whose status is False and ordered by its Order Date.
Here Ordering based on the date is working fine,but orderStatus.cancelled=false is not working. I get all Orders irrespective of cancelled or not cancelled.

**Repository**

```
public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Orders,Integer> {

    @Query("select o from Orders o where o.orderStatus.cancelled=false order by o.orderDate")
    List<Orders> getAllOrders();
}
```

**Orders**

```
@Entity
public class Orders {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private int id;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    @MapsId
    private OrderStatus orderStatus;
}
```

**Order Status**

```
@Entity
public class OrderStatus {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "order_id")
    private int id;
    .....
    .....
    private boolean cancelled;
}
```

Comment: Try 0 instead of false

Comment: Also check the Query class import

Comment: Please share the generated SQL query as can be seen in the log outputs.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
o.orderStatus.cancelled=false
```

to

`o.orderStatus.cancelled='false'` OR `o.orderStatus.cancelled is false`

Answer (score 0):

Change the name of your method e.g:

```
public interface OrdersRepository extends JpaRepository<Orders,Integer> {

    @Query("select o from Orders o where o.orderStatus.cancelled=false order by o.orderDate")
    List<Orders> getAllNonCancelledOrders();
}
```

`getAllOrders()` is a keyword that `JpaRepository` also uses.